# Source windows environment variables in MSYS

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, environment-variables, msys

I have a setenv.cmd script which contains paths for the windows cmd prompt:

```
set CURRENT_SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
set PATH=%PATH%;%CURRENT_SCRIPT_DIR%\bin
```

But I'm using bash (via msys in the git for windows project). Is there a way to source this cmd script in some way but have the variables set in bash? As if I had done `export PATH=...`

Answer (score 2):

Using MSYS2, not sure if the same applies for MSYS.
I have just been looking for the same thing several years later and it turns out the status quo for inheriting the PATH variable is - and I quote from the `msys2_shell.cmd` startup script:

```vb
rem To export full current PATH from environment into MSYS2 use '-use-full-path' parameter
rem or uncomment next line
rem set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit
```